# How to install multiple unsigned extensions in Firefox developer edition?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

> Firefox standard and beta version does not allow unsigned extensions, so I use Firefox developer edition and set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to `false` in `about:config`.

I download source from https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples and use my [**script**](https://github.com/MoYummy/chrome-extensions/blob/master/firefox.py) to build xpi (after putting it to root directory of repo and copying my [**manifest-firefox.json**](https://github.com/MoYummy/chrome-extensions/blob/master/manifest-firefox.json) as well).

For each extension, as you can see from the script, I copy it to a temp folder, modify manifest.json (remove chrome-only fields if any and add gecho for firefox) and zip all into one file.

However, when I tried to install them one by one, I failed to install all.
Every time I installed one, it would replace previous.

Steps:

1. Click `Menu bar - Tools - Add-ons` to open `Add-ons Manager`
2. Click `Extensions` and then gear on the right
3. Click `Install Add-on From File` and choose one under `path/to/webextensions-examples/dist`

Did I miss anything in my build script to cause this? Or is this as designed to only allow one unsigned extension?

Comment: Do you need these to persist after restarting? eg about:debugging?

Comment: @PaulHeil yes, persistent

Comment: I can load more than one using XPIs built with web-ext.  Maybe try that to narrow down the issue

Answer (score 1):

I'm 4 years too late but for anyone that finds this question later this is due to having the same "id" for the multiple extensions if you're using "browser_specific_settings" in your manifest